# VirtualBox WinXP Host - Win 2000 guest internet connection issue

Tags: windows-xp, virtualization, windows-2000, internet

VirtualBox WinXP Host - Win 2000 guest internet connection issue
I'm using a NAT network adapter, but I get no connectivity. 
I can ping websites and get replies but cannot open them in the browser anyone? help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason my internet explorer was set to proxy, after removing it worked!

Comment: It's strange that this would affect VirtualBox. Regardless, you should look at using bridged mode for your VM networking, because it's much faster and less error prone.